# Old slasher movie from the 80s where people die in ways that are based on their names

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched this movie decades ago on cable TV and for the dear life of me I cannot remember anything other than those assorted details:

- The movie was about two college students investigating a series of murders in a college campus.
- The killer's gimmick is that they murdered people based on their names.
- One of the victims was a guy called Burns. Naturally he was burnt alive. To elaborate: Guy was conducting an experiment late night in the Chemistry lab that went awry and set his left arm on fire. He calmly went to the emergency shower but instead of dousing him he burst into flames. Turned out that the killer had switched the shower's pipeline with a gas pipe. Hilariously, despite being reduced to a charred skeleton, guy could still move his eyes and gave a side glance like he was wondering what the hell happened.
- Another victim was a woman poisoned with toxic mushrooms. One of the main characters said something about the woman name's being related to mushrooms.
- The last victim was another woman that got shoved down a garbage chute and ended up impaled in trash. Once again the main characters said something about the victim's name being related to the way she died.

Does anything on this wall of text ring a bell?

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like [Getting In](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109893/combined) (AKA Student Body) from 1994, which starred a  number of famous names. From [Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/getting_in/):

> An attempted black comedy, Getting In endeavors to satirize the cut-throat competition surrounding the medical school admissions process -- a struggle that in this case literally turns deadly. Gabriel Higgs is an aspiring medical student, not out of a great dedication to his craft but due to pressure by his parents, who expect him to follow the long-standing family tradition of attending Johns Hopkins and embarking upon a prominent medical career. However, a poor showing in the admissions test and several other mishaps conspire to place Gabriel on the school's waiting list. Desperate to gain entrance to the school before being disinherited, Gabriel takes to bribing his fellow waiting-list candidates to ensure his admission. **But when the students at the top of the waiting list start turning up dead in rather nasty ways, Gabriel finds himself in real trouble. He must discover who is committing these crimes before he is blamed -- or becomes the next victim himself.** Easily forgettable, the film is mainly notable for featuring early performances by future television stars Matthew Perry and Calista Flockhart, and for being the directorial debut of Doug Liman, who would receive critical acclaim for his second film, Swingers.

So it's from the 90s and more of a funny thriller than a slasher movie, but according to [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109893/trivia):

> **Both Randall Burns and Amanda Morel are killed off in a method that matches their respective surnames. Burns is burned to death, and Morel accidentally eats poisoned Morel mushrooms and dies of food poisoning.**

Here's the trailer, where you can see Burns' (played by Matthew Perry) arm catching on fire in the lab just like you described, around 1:18:

Comment: @InternetRoyalty Cool, glad it helped! Don't forget to approve the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.